# SMW #ask query for Results Format graph

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I have a number of pages in Semantic MediaWiki linked in a kind hierarchy by a property called `Is implemented by`.

E.g

- "Widget Plant in Belgium" `Is implemented by` "Widget Plant with XYZ"
- "Widget Plant with XYZ" `Is implemented by` "Module A of XYZ"
- "Widget Plant with XYZ" `Is implemented by` "Module B of XYZ"

How can I write an `#ask` query on the "Widget Plant in Belgium" page which will show a graph of all the pages via `Is implemented by` properties using `format=graph`

I have GraphViz and Semantics Results Formats installed and they appear to be working.

Ideally I'd like to put this query in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
{{#ask:[[Is implemented by::+]]
| ?Is implemented by
| format=graph
| graphname = Implementations
| graphcolor=yes
| graphsize = 800,800
| graphfontsize = 9
| graphlegend = yes
| graphlink = yes
| relation = child
| arrowdirection = RL
| nodelabel = displaytitle
}}
```

`[[Is implemented by::+]]` means that 'orphans' (unimplemented entites) will not appear. If this is not what is wanted, make sure that all entities are in a category, e.g. `[[Category:Implementations]]` and replace the query condition with `[[Category:Implementations]]`; or you can use `[[Some definitely defined, and only for implementations, property::+]]`.